# Can't find refresh token when Cognito redirects back to my URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

I'm testing with AWS's Cognito. At this point, I can get back my `IdToken`, `AccessToken`, and `RefreshToken` like this:

```
$ aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth --user-pool-id us-east-1_XXXXXXXX --client-id XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --auth-flow ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH --auth-parameters USERNAME=XXXXXXXXXXXXX,PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXXXXXX --region us-east-1
```

Then I tried the default web page (provided by Cognito) at a URL like this:

```
https://test-cognito.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://example.com
```

This URL will take me to a page where I have to authenticate and once the process is done it will take me back to my `redirect_url` with previously mentioned IDs appended:

```
https://example.com#id_token=XXXXX.XXXXXX.XXXXXX&access_token=XXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer
```

But there's no sign of `refresh_token`! How can I get my `refresh_token` in this scenario?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that is possible at present. AWS clearly states that refresh token is only available if the flow type is `Authorization Code Grant`.

What you are trying is `Implicit Grant`. The responseType is set to `token` in your case. For Authorization Code Grant, set the grant type to `code` but that will also need you to store the client secret in the app.

Source- https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/refresh-token.html.

For more info on grant types - https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/